# Is this Fourier series some combination of Eisenstein series?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, special-functions, modular-forms

Consider the twisted Eisenstein series
$$
\begin{align}
 E_{k \ge 1}\left[\begin{matrix}
  \phi \\ \theta
 \end{matrix}\right] := & \ - \frac{B_k(\lambda)}{k!} \\
 & \ + \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\sum_{r \ge 0}' \frac{(r + \lambda)^{k - 1}\theta^{-1} q^{r + \lambda}}{1 - \theta^{-1}q^{r + \lambda}}
 + \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1)!}\sum_{r \ge 1} \frac{(r - \lambda)^{k - 1}\theta q^{r - \lambda}}{1 - \theta q^{r - \lambda}} \ ,
\end{align}
$$
where $\phi = e^{2\pi i \lambda}, q = e^{2\pi i \tau}$. We know that they all can be written in Fourier series, for example,
$$
E_1 \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
 = \frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \ne 0} \frac{1}{\sin n \pi \tau} e^{2\pi i n \mathfrak{z}} \ ,
\qquad
E_2 \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
 = - \frac{1}{12} -\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \ne 0} \frac{1}{\sin^2 n \pi \tau} e^{2\pi i n \mathfrak{z}} \ ,
$$
where $z = e^{2\pi i \mathfrak{z}}$.

Recently I run into the following series
$$
\sum_{\substack{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\\m,n,m+n \ne 0}}\frac{1}{\sin m \pi \tau\sin n \pi \tau \sin (m + n) \pi \tau}e^{2\pi i (m+n) \mathfrak{z}} \ .
$$
**I wonder if this can be rewritten in terms of Eisenstein series? Or is it known to be some other special functions?**

============Update============

With some guess work and help from Mathematica, I think the answer is the following
$$
\sum_{\substack{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\\m,n,m+n \ne 0}}\frac{1}{\sin m \pi \tau\sin n \pi \tau \sin (m + n) \pi \tau}e^{2\pi i (m+n) \mathfrak{z}} \\
= - \frac{\vartheta'_1(\mathfrak{z})\vartheta''_1(\mathfrak{z})}{2\pi^3\vartheta_1(\mathfrak{z})^2}
+ \frac{\vartheta'''_1 (\mathfrak{z})}{6\pi^3\vartheta_1'(\mathfrak{z})}
+ 4 E_2(\tau) \frac{\vartheta_1'(\mathfrak{z})}{\pi\vartheta_1(\mathfrak{z})} \ ,
$$
where $E_2(\tau)$ is the standard quasi-modular Eisenstein series. In terms of twisted Eisenstein series, it reads
$$
- 8 i \Bigg(
E_3 \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
+ E_2 \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
E_1 \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
- E_2(\tau)E_1 \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
\Bigg)
$$

**However, a proof is still lacking.**

The guessed result is a **quasi-Jacobi form of modular weight-three**. If  this were known beforehand, one can always make an anzatz in terms of the twisted Eisenstein series and work out the relative coefficients using Mathematica. So a relevant question would be: **how to argue that the series gives rise to such a quasi-Jacobi form?**